# Reference type inside Value type in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

Structures are value type in C# and string is reference type. I know the difference in their memory allocation and mapping, but I am not sure how C# reference types are stored inside value type. Let's say I have a string inside the following structure.
If Reference type inside Structure are created On heap then how Compiler Manages Data on heap when Structure is passed as parameter to function.

**Will the string be created on stack or heap?**

If I pass object of Struct **Point** to function how does .net manages Object of **PointC** inside Struct. if PointC is created on heap then passing stuct to function will have the same memories as of class ?

```
   public class PointC
    {
      ...
      ...
    }
   public struct Point
    {
      PointC obj;
    }
```

Comment: I would *guess* that the string is still on the heap and the *reference* is on the stack. Such distinctions are typically not useful in C# though.

Comment: `I know the difference in their memory allocation and mapping` Your question indicates that you do not in fact know that...

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Propagating the idea that value types go on the stack is only contributing to the problem.  Value types don't go on the stack, they go wherever the particular storage location for the variable in question goes, which could be pretty much anywhere, including the stack, heap, or neither.

Comment: [The Stack Is An Implementation Detail, Part One](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/) ,  [Part 2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/04/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-two/)

Comment: What problem is this solving?  One of the features of .Net is to remove the need for programmers to know this.  Unless you are actually having a problem, this isn't a good question.

Comment: Also, [The Truth About Value Types](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types/) **in the Microsoft implementation of C# on the desktop CLR, value types are stored on the stack when the value is a local variable or temporary that is not a closed-over local variable of a lambda or anonymous method, and the method body is not an iterator block, and the jitter chooses to not enregister the value**

Answer (score 1):

The reference will be created on the stack (or more specifically it will be where the struct will be).

The reference will have a default value (null), so no String object will be created at the struct construction.

The String object and the string buffer will be created in the heap when you allocate the string via string constructor.